# How to connect BlackBerry10 Dev Alpha B to QNX Momentics

Tags: blackberry-10, qnx, blackberry-qnx

How to connect BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha B device to QNX Momentics?

I've tried to connect it with

Window > Preferences.
 Expand BlackBerry, and then select Signing.
 Click BlackBerry Deployment Setup Wizard.

And when I got to the part where QNX Momentics should detect my device IP adress it fails, it can't find the device's IP adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the device is set to development mode.  You can find this under settings->security.

I'm not sure if it's fixed for latest versions or not, but note that sometimes after going into sleep mode or being rebooted you might need to turn development mode on again.

Edit (thanks to Naskov):
Also install the BlackBerry10 driver that the device is offering to install.

Comment: Also to Install the BlackBerry10 driver that the device is offering to install. Expand the answer with that :)

Answer (score 1):

It addition to Hyarion's answer also go under Settings->Storage and Access and set "Connect to Windows"/"Connect to Mac" depending on what you're using. I find this works better than letting the device autodetect what kind of computer you have.